# How can I run complex piped commands in Autoinstall / Cloud-Init?

Tags: cloud-init

In either cloud-init user-data runcmd, or in autoinstall late-commands, I need to essentially run this command as part of a Clevis + Tang initialization for a LUKS encrypted volume:

```
echo '<secret>' | clevis luks bind -d /dev/sda2 tang '{"url": "http://<ip-tangserver>" , "adv": "/tmp/adv.jws" }'
```

The problem is, I'm having a hard time determining if this is actually possible using either runcmd or late-commands, and if so, how I can do this in a YAML-compliant way, eg:

```
runcmd:
  - echo 'some-luks-temp-passwd' | clevis luks bind -d /dev/vda3 tang '{"url": "http://192.168.122.150" , "adv": "/tmp/adv.jws" }'
```

Enclosing the entire string above doesn't seem to work either, yamllint still shows a syntax error:

```
runcmd:
  - "echo 'some-luks-temp-passwd' | clevis luks bind -d /dev/vda3 tang '{"url": "http://192.168.122.150" , "adv": "/tmp/adv.jws" }'"
```

Thanks!

Comment: try this `bash -c 'echo '\''<secret>'\'' | clevis luks bind -d /dev/sda2 tang '\''{"url": "http://<ip-tangserver>" , "adv": "/tmp/adv.jws" }'\'''`

Comment: What I did is put the thing I want to run in a file and do `i=$(cat tmp)` next run this `set | grep "^i="` remove the "i=" part, and you're good

Comment: Thanks @lnee, but it looks like the escaping above still results in yamllint failures. 
`syntax error: expected <block end>, but found ','`

I'm going to keep on digging but thank you for the option to try!

Comment: `bash -c "$(xxd -r -p <<<"hexblob)" ` replace "hexblob" with the output of this `hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X "' "REPLACEWITHFILETHAT HAS YOUR CODE" |sed -e 's/ //g'" `      (note code was taken from https://github.com/lnee94/resh/blob/main/l/bintools)

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to use [YAML multiline syntax](https://yaml-multiline.info/).  I'm not sure what is failing with your current syntax, but here is an `autoinstall` snippet that uses json, piping, output redirection, and Heredoc in multiline syntax.

```
#cloud-config
runcmd:
  - |
    echo '{"foo":"FOO" , "bar" : "BAR"}' > /run/cmd.log
    cat <<EOF | xxd >> /run/cmd.log
    {
      "foo": "FOO",
      "bar": "BAR"
    }
    EOF
```

FWIW, this is the resulting `/run/cmd.log` file

```
root@ubuntu-server:/# cat /run/cmd.log
{"foo":"FOO" , "bar" : "BAR"}
00000000: 7b0a 2020 2266 6f6f 223a 2022 464f 4f22  {.  "foo": "FOO"
00000010: 2c0a 2020 2262 6172 223a 2022 4241 5222  ,.  "bar": "BAR"
00000020: 0a7d 0a                                  .}.
```