# early_command equivalent in cloud-init

Tags: preseed, cloud-init, debian-installer

I have an Ubuntu installer based on [Ubuntu mini.iso](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/mini.iso) which uses preseed. Now with [the support for mini.iso, being stopped by Canonical](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/netbooting-the-live-server-installer/14510/2), I'm trying to create an installer based on [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html). However, with this, I couldn't see an option equivalent to early_command in preseed, (which helped me do some complicated partitioning via scripting and added some checks)

Is there any such option available with cloud-init?

Comment: [Bootcmd](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#bootcmd) looks similar - no luck with it?

Answer (score 3):

When using autoinstall with the "live server" installer (*subiquity*) there are three options that could replace the preseed `early_command` setting.  If you are creating your own installer (and not using *subiquity*) then you can ignore the autoinstall option.

- [bootcmd](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#bootcmd) in cloud-init
- [runcmd](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#runcmd) in cloud-init
- [early-commands](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference#early-commands) in autoinstall

These run at different points during an install.  Here is a snippet of a cloud-init autoinstall file with all three defined.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  early-commands:
    - echo "early-commands" >> /run/my.log
runcmd:
  - echo "runcmd" >> /run/my.log
bootcmd:
  - echo "bootcmd" >> /run/my.log
```

**see also**

- [How can I run complex piped commands in Autoinstall / Cloud-Init?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390768/how-can-i-run-complex-piped-commands-in-autoinstall-cloud-init)

**notes**

I tested using Ubuntu 22.04 (`subiquity 22.04.2`)