# Using sed insert or append for ubuntu autoinstall

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, sed

I use following command in my ubuntu auto-install `late-commands` to append a line in my `/etc/aliases` file:

```bash
sed -i -e '/^postmaster:.*/i\'$'root:           root' /target/etc/aliases
```

I also tried POSIX not conform version:

```bash
sed -i '/^postmaster:.*/i root:           root' /target/etc/aliases
```

Both with the same result while installing:

```
finish: subiquity/Late/load_autoinstall_data: {"sed -i -e '/^postmaster:.*/i\\'$'root": "root' /target/etc/aliases"} is not of type 'string', 'array'
```

I think I understand the issue: The Column-Space is interpreted by yaml or something else as yaml entry. At least this message leads in my opinion to this problem.

I thought since `late-commands` are already multiline commands this would not be any issue.

I also tried using double quotes instead of single quotes.

Any Idea how to achieve the wanted behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

> I thought since late-commands are already multiline commands this would not be any issue.

Why do you think this?  It sounds like you are using a single-line of YAML and thinking it will behave like multiline YAML.

I was able to use this YAML multiline syntax without any errors

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  late-commands:
    - |
      sed -i '/^postmaster:.*/i root:           root' /target/etc/aliases
      true
```

I use `true` at the end of the command so that if `sed` exits with a non-zero return code then it will not stop the installer from continuing.  For example, if `/target/etc/aliases` does not exist.

**see also**

- [How can I run complex piped commands in Autoinstall / Cloud-Init?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390768/how-can-i-run-complex-piped-commands-in-autoinstall-cloud-init)

**notes**

There did appear to be some syntax/escaping issue with the dollar sign.  When I tried this configuration

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  late-commands:
    - |
      cat <<EOF > /run/aliases
      postmaster:root
      EOF
      sed -i -e '/^postmaster:.*/i\'$'root:           root' /run/aliases
      sed -i '/^postmaster:.*/i root:           root' /run/aliases
      true
```

The resulting `/run/aliases` file content was

```
$root:           root
root:           root
postmaster:root
```

I tested using Ubuntu 22.04 (`subiquity 22.04.2`)

Comment: > Why do you think this? I didn't just used a single command. I've added a list of command with `- <command1>\n - <commander2>`. I didn't know that nesting is still possible with this syntax.

Comment: Still wondering, that it ignored the single quotes. Seems to be the same issue in the other question. I am also not sure if the true is reasonable, since if /etc/aliases is not existence postfix isn't installed.