# How to add shell script and python scripts in ubuntu auto-install early-commands section

Tags: server, user-data, autoinstall

I have a requirement to add multiple shell scripts and python scripts in the ubuntu autoinstall early-command section.

All documents tell about only the shell commands passing procedure inside early-commands and non of them are telling about the script passing procedure.

If anyone knows please let me know how to inject scripts inside early-commands, examples would be more helpful.

user-data file is :

```
#cloud-config

autoinstall:

  version: 1

  identity:

    hostname: ubuntu

    password: "password"

    username: ubuntu

  interactive-sections:

   - network

  locale: en_US

  storage:

    layout:

        name: direct

  ssh:

    allow-pw: yes

    install-server: true

  user-data:

    disable_root: false

  
  early-commands:
  
  - ?                       #need to add scripts here
```

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/a/1392251/376778

Comment: Thanks but not helped for my requirement.